# Getting output of one Stored Procedure called in another using TSQL

Tags: t-sql, dynamic-programming, stored-functions

I have two stored procedures spParent and spParentChild.  spParent calls spParentChild.  Following the SPs:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spParent]
        @isApproved varchar(max) = 'TEST',
        @ApplicationDBName varchar(100) = 'secDB',
        @ApplicationInsertSPName varchar(100) = 'spParentChild',
        @resultP varchar(max) output
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        IF @resultP <> ''
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('An error occurred in the parent SP.', 18, 0)
        END

        DECLare @resultCC varchar(max)
        DECLARE @SP_Call Varchar(MAX)
        SET @SP_Call = 'exec spParentChild ''1'', @resultCC output'
        EXEC @SP_Call 
        select @resultCC
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        Declare @ErrMessage Varchar(max)
        Declare @ErrState Varchar(max)
        Declare @ErrLine Varchar(max)

        select @ErrMessage=ErrorMessage, @ErrLine=ErrorLine, @ErrState=ErrorState  from fnGetError()

        IF @ErrMessage is not Null
        BEGIN
            SELECT @resultP = @ErrMessage
            SELECT @resultCC
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @resultP = 'An unknown error occurred.'
            raiserror(@resultP,18,0)
        END
    END CATCH
END

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spParentChild]
        @isApproved varchar(max) = 'TEST',
        @resultC varchar(max)   output  
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        RAISERROR('An error occurred in the child SP.', 18, 0)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        Declare @ErrMessage Varchar(max)
        Declare @ErrState Varchar(max)
        Declare @ErrLine Varchar(max)

        select @ErrMessage=ErrorMessage, @ErrLine=ErrorLine, @ErrState=ErrorState  from fnGetError()

        IF @ErrMessage is not Null
        BEGIN
            SET @resultC = @ErrMessage
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @resultC = 'An unknown error occurred.'
        END
    END CATCH
END
```

As you can see spParent calls spParentChild.  What I am needing is to use TSQL for the call, but it does not work.  If I use the following all works fine, but I need TSQL:

```
EXEC spParentChild 1, @resultCC output
```

Can anyone help me in seeing what I am doing wrong or if this is even possible at all?

Thank you in advance.

Godfrey

Comment: Why `SET @SP_Call = 'exec spParentChild ''1'', @resultCC output' ;EXEC @SP_Call;`? Just do `exec spParentChild ''1'', @resultCC output;` There's no need for a "dynamic" statement.

Comment: Also `EXEC @SP_Call` would translate to `EXEC EXEC ...` which will obviously fail.

Comment: Apologies, the actual TSQL does not have the exec in it.  The SP I am trying to change is far more complex and requires TSQL.

Comment: All of the above is T-SQL, @Jeff, but your statement isn't dynamic, so it doesn't need a dynamic statement.

Comment: I just realized that one of my issues is @resultCC not being local to the exec statement.  The SP I am trying to change has a ton of XML that is used to pass to another database. The XML is being build from a passed in variable.  I am thinking that this is not possible.  I thank you all for your time. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To those who have a similar problem or need I am posting this solution I put together.  It  may sound as if this is crazy, but please believe when I tell you that I do require this and the actual SPs that need this are too long to post.

The spParentChild has not changed and remains as above.  spParent is changed as shown below.  The result is that spParent calls spParentChild. In his case if an error occurs in spParentChild the message is passed up to spParent in the output parameter.

I shall attempt to answer any questions should you have any.  Following is spParent:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spParent]
        @isApproved varchar(max) = 'TEST',
        @ApplicationDBName varchar(100) = 'SecDB',
        @ApplicationInsertSPName varchar(100) = 'spParentChild',
        @resultP varchar(max) output
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        IF @resultP <> ''
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('An error occurred in the parent SP.', 18, 0)
        END

        DECLARE @params NVarChar(max)
        SET @params = '@resultCC VarChar(100) OUTPUT' -- OUTPUT Parameter for the called child SP
        DECLARE @SP_Call NVarchar(MAX) -- sp_executesql requires NVarChar
        SET @SP_Call = '[' + @ApplicationDBName + '].[dbo].[' + @ApplicationInsertSPName + '] ' + ' ''1'', @resultCC OUTPUT' -- ResultCC is the output parameter for the sp_executesql
        EXEC sp_executesql @SP_Call, @params, @resultCC = @resultP OUTPUT -- Assign the value to the output parameter of this SP

        -- EXEC spParentChild 1, @resultCC output -- THE ABOVE 5 LINES OF CODE ARE EQUAL TO THIS IS A HARDCODED CALL
        if @resultP <> ''
        BEGIN
            SELECT @resultP [Returned Value]
        END

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        Declare @ErrMessage Varchar(max)
        Declare @ErrState Varchar(max)
        Declare @ErrLine Varchar(max)

        select @ErrMessage=ErrorMessage, @ErrLine=ErrorLine, @ErrState=ErrorState  from fnGetError()

        IF @ErrMessage is not Null
        BEGIN
            SELECT @resultP = @ErrMessage
            SELECT @ErrMessage
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @resultP = 'An unknown error occurred.'
            SELECT 'bbb'
            raiserror(@resultP,18,0)
        END
    END CATCH
END
```

I hope this assists someone in such need.